# Deno: request getting called twice

Tags: javascript, deno

```
import { serve } from "https://deno.land/std@0.50.0/http/server.ts";
const s = serve({ port: 8000 });
console.log("http://localhost:8000/");
// listing to  requests 
for await (const req of s) {
    const res = await fetch('https://api.github.com/users')
    let data = await res.json()
    console.log('test- call')
    req.respond({ body:JSON.stringify(data)});
}
```

In the above code, when I try hitting http://localhost:8000/, I could see the console logging twice 'test- call'.

Not sure why is this happening. Help required to understand.

Comment: If you're navigating there with your browser, it could be your browser making a request for `favicon.ico`. If you open your browser's developer tools' network tab, you'll probably see it there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is actually running fine.

If you try to access `http://localhost:8000` with a `browser`, this is the output:

```sh
$ open web browser http://localhost:8000
test- call GET /
test- call GET /favicon.ico <- extra
```

However, if you access it with `curl` then you will see only one output as expected:

```sh
$ curl localhost:8000
test- call GET /
```

To see the extra request, log request details:

```sh
console.log('test- call', req.method, req.url)
```

Hope it helps!